# How to retrieve a decrypted value from secrets manager in AWS CodeBuild

Tags: aws-codebuild

I have a following buildspec.yaml,

```
env:
  secrets-manager:
    githubPAT: "TestSecret:MY_SECRET_VAR"
    
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t $ECR_IMAGE_TAG --build-arg githubPAT=$githubPAT
```

In a Dockerfile, githubPAT is used for adding nuget source as below.

```
ARG githubPAT
RUN echo ${githubPAT}
RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/XXXX/index.json" --name github --username XXXXX --password ${githubPAT} --store-password-in-clear-text
```

But it gives me an error saying,

```
Step 10/24 : RUN echo ${githubPAT}
 ---> Running in 2614b5a0da1b
***
error: Password encryption is not supported on .NET Core for this platform. The following feed try to use an encrypted password: 'github'. You can use a clear text password as a workaround.
error:   Encryption is not supported on non-Windows platforms.
```

It seems like the value from secrets manager is encrypted but github nuget source requires a decrypted value. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Oh it seems like my Dockerfile has a problem, not secrets manager in CodeBuild. I'm still trying to track down a bug though